# If $F_n$ is the $n^{th}$ Fibonacci number, how do I find $F_{340}$ (mod $7$)?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Consider the following problem

> If $F_n$ is the $n^{th}$ Fibonacci number, what is $F_{340}$ (mod $7$)?

My first try was to use [Binet's Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsFibonacciNumberFormula.html) to find a closed form for $F_{340}$ and then apply the usual modulo computation techniques. The problem is that this is an extremely large number! So now I am not sure what to do.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisano_period

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. Consider the sequence $f_n:=F_n \pmod{7}$. Then
$f_{n+1}\equiv f_{n}+f_{n-1}  \pmod{7}$.

Moreover for $n\geq 0$, $f_n$ is equal to
$$0,1,1,2,3,5,1,6,0,6,6,5,4,2,6,1,0,1\dots$$
Since we have again the couple 0,1 and the next term is determined by the two previous terms, the sequence is periodic! The period is $0,1,1,2,3,5,1,6,0,6,6,5,4,2,6,1$ with length $16$.

Comment: I suspected this might have been what you were getting at before you added the sequence! I am now wondering, is a hint of periodicity enough for us to assume that it will continue being this way? How do we know for sure that ALL the residues will continue to follow this cycle?

Comment: Because after 2,6,1 it becomes 0,1 and the next term depends on the last two terms only.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I had forgotten that you could just use the Fibonacci recurrence using the residues, and was rather looking at the actual numbers themselves and then taking the residue.

Answer (score 2):

All I know about Fibonacci numbers is that $F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}.$ So I started calculating Fibonacci numbers modulo $7,$ starting with $F_0=0$ and $F_1=1,$ and I soon found that $F_{16}\equiv0\equiv F_0\pmod7$ and $F_{17}\equiv1\equiv F_1\pmod7.$ So it looks like $F_n\equiv F_{n+16}\pmod7$ for all $n.$